# Limit results instead of group results

Tags: mysql, database

I am struggling to find the right answer looking around the internet for how to do this, I have a join and a group. When I add a Limit to the end it limits the groups and not the actual results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`, `people`.`age` 
FROM (`events`) 
JOIN `people` 
ON `events`.`id` = `people`.`id`
WHERE `people`.`priority` = '1' 
GROUP BY `people`.`age` 
ORDER BY `numrows` 
LIMIT 150
```

The limit always changes so this needs to be dynamic, the idea is to miss out the first 150 or x amount of rows from both tables but not the to limit the groups.

EDIT= I think I have explained this badly, I actually want to start from 150 rows or x, limit is the only way I know to do this dynamically. so the idea is if the last search was retrieved 150 rows, then lets say next time there are 250 results but I want to ignore the first 150 which were found last time etc.. Hope that makes better sense.

there limit or start from needs to be after the WHERE in the join, I think that's the only place it would work.

EDIT SQL =

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS `numrows`, `people`.`age`
FROM (
SELECT `id`, `events`.`pid`
FROM `events`
ORDER BY `id`
LIMIT 1050
)limited
JOIN `people` ON `people`.`age` = limited.id
WHERE `people`.`priority` = '1'
GROUP BY `people`.`age`
ORDER BY `numrows` DESC
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: not really i understand your question

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  The SQL is well-formed to retrieve 150 rows of the output set.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows, people.age
FROM (
SELECT id FROM events ORDER BY id LIMIT 150
) limited
JOIN people ON people.id = limited.id
GROUP BY people.age
ORDER BY numrows;
```

Comment: Ok this nearly worked, but because I explained it badly it doesn't do what I want it to do, it does limit the events table but then it misses out the results because I missed off a where clause which changes please look above

Answer (score 0):

I did it using where between on timestamp, it seems like the only sensible way to do it.